# Lyft/Scissors image cropping library not loading big images

Tags: android, image

I'm using [Scissors by Lyft](https://github.com/lyft/scissors) to crop images in my app. The cropper works fine for images up to a certain size but is unable to load big images into the crop view. I tried using Picasso to load images into the cropView but that didn't work either.

I can't upload my whole class here but here are relevant snippets.

```
import com.lyft.android.scissors.CropView;

private CropView mCropView;

//This is where it fails. For big images I get an Out Of Memory Exception and the cropView remains blank.
private void handleImagePickedFromGallery(Intent data) {
       Uri imageUri = data.getData();
       mCropView.extensions().load(imageUri);
}

//this is called when the user clicks on the
//crop button below the cropView
private void onCropClicked() {
    mCroppedImage = mCropView.crop();   //get cropped image
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.ic_image);

    mCropView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(mCroppedImage);    //load cropped image

    mFab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check));    //change crop icon to done
}
```

And this is the XML (doubt this will be useful):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.rbc.imageselector.ImageControllerActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Image selected by user"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <com.lyft.android.scissors.CropView
        android:id="@+id/crop_view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/ic_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cropviewViewportRatio="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/crop_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_crop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```